# Execute arbitrary code after return statement PHP?

Tags: php, security, return, eval

I have an eval() vulnerability that I need exploit in PHP:

`eval("return ".$somevalue." ;")`

I can set the `$somevalue` to whatever text I want. I want to echo something, but that gives an error, as php `echo` and `print` are not functions. I can set the text to a built-in php function like getcwd(), but the return value is then lost later in the program. I want to use the eval to execute arbitrary code, but the return is tripping me up. If I close the return with `false; my_code_here` than all my code won't run.

How do you execute arbitrary code after a PHP return statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I am not sure if this is the best way but it works:

`(function() { echo 'Function Run'; return false; })()`

This declares a new function and executes it in one line. Thus it is allowed after a `return`.